# error 404 page not found (laravel 5.8)(like button route)

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I want to add like button to my posts but when I'm clicking on button getting a 404 error.

this is my view

```
<form action="{{route('user.like', ['postId' => $post->id, 'userId' => Auth::user()->id])}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" role="button" value="like"/>
</form>
```

the route

```
Route::post('/user{userId}/post{postId}/like',[
    'uses' => 'postController@like',
    'as' => 'user.like'
]);
```

and this is my controller

```
    public function like($postId, $userId){
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
        $user->votedPosts()->attach($postId);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I really have no idea why im getting error 404.

Comment: try to edit it to 
`Route::post('like/{postId}/{userId}',[
    'uses' => 'postController@like',
    'as' => 'user.like'
]);`

Comment: thank you so much. do you have a link or something why we should do it this way?

Comment: in your route you pass `userId` then `postId` but in your controller, you made the opposite

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I'm trying but the site gives me an alert and it says i have to wait for 3 minutes!

Comment: you need to wait 3 minutes :(

Comment: do you know why i should wait?

Comment: really no i don't maybe just for check the best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while you try to bind variable in your route 
it written in this way `{userId}` not `userId{userId}`

so it will be like this

```
Route::post('like/{postId}/{userId}',[ 
  'uses' => 'postController@like', 
   'as' => 'user.like' ]);
```

you can check more in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters)